# Necessary libraries for openMPI and Singularity software containers?

Tags: r, openmpi, hpc, singularity-container

## Question

For deployment of [singularity software containers](http://singularity.lbl.gov/) on HPC systems, is it better to

1. copy from host,
2. bind to host,
3. or install during bootstrap

relevant HPC libraries into the container? If strategy 1. or 2. are generally recommendable, how do I find out which libraries need copying/binding and where from/to?

Better may refer to better ease of use, better stability and efficiency of the solution, or better independence and reproducibilty of the solution.

So far I have mostly tried strategy 3. and relied on error or warning messages with respect to which libraries to install. That was unsuccessful, however.

---

## Background

The ultimate goal of the container is to run R in parallel via openMPI on an HPC system. A minimal bootstrap definition file to get running in parallel looks like this for me.

```
Bootstrap: debootstrap
OSVersion: xenial
MirrorURL: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

%post
  # add universe repository
  sed -i 's/main/main universe/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

  apt-get update    
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends r-base-dev libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin
  apt-get clean

  # directory will be bound to host
  mkdir /etc/libibverbscd .d

  # Interface R and MPI
  R --slave -e 'install.packages("doMPI", repos="http://cloud.r-project.org/")'


%runscript
  R -e "library(doMPI); cl <- startMPIcluster(count = 5); registerDoMPI(cl); foreach(i=1:5) %dopar% Sys.sleep(10); closeCluster(cl); mpi.quit()"
```

With this I can execute

```
singularity run -B /etc/libibverbs.d/:/etc/libibverbs.d/ test.img
```

and get a few warning messages, but (so far) it works. Warnings:

```
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't load driver 'ipathverbs': libipathverbs-rdmav2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't load driver 'mthca': libmthca-rdmav2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[12293,2],0]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: ****

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
[****:01978] 4 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-btl-base.txt / btl:no-nics
[****:01978] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

I have tried installing packages `libipathverbs1` and `libmthca1`, which will make the warning messages disappear, but then running in parallel fails:

```
An MPI process has executed an operation involving a call to the
"fork()" system call to create a child process.  Open MPI is currently
operating in a condition that could result in memory corruption or
other system errors; your MPI job may hang, crash, or produce silent
data corruption.  The use of fork() (or system() or other calls that
create child processes) is strongly discouraged.

The process that invoked fork was:

  Local host:          ****
  MPI_COMM_WORLD rank: 1

If you are *absolutely sure* that your application will successfully
and correctly survive a call to fork(), you may disable this warning
by setting the mpi_warn_on_fork MCA parameter to 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> -------------------------------------------------------
Child job 2 terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
```

[Here](http://singularity.lbl.gov/tutorial-gpu-drivers-open-mpi-mtls) it is suggested to bind the relevant libraries, but I am not sure which of them or which others I would need or even how to find out about it (besides very tedious trial-and-error).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the OMPI FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=openfabrics#ofa-fork), you cannot call fork when using IB, unless the fork is followed directly by an exec call. I bet you have another program or library that forks in your code, which crashes OpenMPI.